# Save both or neither model in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to save two models in one controller action, or save neither, and return with the validation errors.

Is there a better way than this?

```
def update
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    @location = @job.location

    @job.assign_attributes(job_params)
    @location.assign_attributes(location_params)
    @job.save unless @job.valid? # gets validation errors
    @location.save unless @location.valid? # gets validation errors

    if @job.valid? && @location.valid?
      @job.save
      @location.save
      flash[:success] = "Changes saved."
      redirect_to edit_job_path(@job)
    else
      render 'edit' 
    end
  end
```

New version:

```
def update
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  @location = @job.location

  begin
    Job.transaction do
      @job.assign_attributes(job_params)
      @job.save!(job_params)
      @location.assign_attributes(location_params)
      @location.save!(location_params)
    end
    flash[:success] = "Changes saved."
    redirect_to edit_job_path(@job)
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: Why are you calling `save` twice for each instance?

Comment: If you don't wanna use `nested_attributes` like the answers suggest (which I recommend), you could use an ActiveRecord#transaction (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) and use `save!` inside this block, rescue the "Record not valid" error and render the proper view.

Comment: Thanks MrYoshiji! The reasoning against accepts_nested_attributes_for is that job belongs_to location.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Active Record Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).
Using Nested attributes, you can save associated record attributes through parent.If parent record fails, associated records won't be saved.!

Comment: Thanks! The reasoning against accepts_nested_attributes_for is that job belongs_to a location. I don't think you can accepts_nested_attributes_for parents

Answer (score 1):

the first thing you'd want to do is delete these two lines

```
@job.save unless @job.valid? # gets validation errors
@location.save unless @location.valid? # gets validation errors
```

and only keep the `#save` in the if statement. because if one of them is valid, but the other isn't, you'll still save the valid one to the db.
To answer your second question, is there a better way to do this? At first blush, it looks like a job for [#accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for). However, accepts_nested_attributes_for is somewhat notorious for being difficult to get working (really it just takes a fare amount of tinkering) and what you're currently doing should get you where you're trying to go, so it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. The reasoning against accepts_nested_attributes_for is that job belongs_to location.

Answer (score 1):

You can use validates_associated rails helper:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location
  validates_associated :location
end
```

Then:

```
if @job.save
  #blah
else
  #blah
end
```

Is enough without having to mess with ActiveRecord#Nested_attributes. It's fastest, but less cleaner. Your choice.

Reference:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_associated